# Move object continuously after being triggered by near sensor

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Can the near sensor be use a switch?
Having Cube1 near Cylinder I want the Cube1 to do a infinite continuous movement.

In my [file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33921) Cube1 stops once it goes out of range of the near sensor. Is there a way to make it move forever once it triggers the near sensor?

Comment: Try to describe your problem as best as you can, not everyone has the time to pull down your file and poke around to see what you want.

Comment: That's the _point_ of the near sensor.

Comment: There was some confusion about what you were asking, so I've edited your question to try and make it clearer. If I'm wrong, feel free to roll back my edits and/or edit it again :)

Answer (score 4):

Although you could have the reset distance at 10,000 blender units before it stops moving, and this may work for what you want, that is not at all the correct way to do this.

From what I can tell from your question, you want to have the cube detect being near the cylinder, and then after that, you want the cube to continuously move. The Near sensor detects the distance from the cylinder, and that sets the Boolean property to true. When the Boolean property is true, it will continuously make the cube move.

If you wanted to make the cube stop moving, you could simply have another property actuator assign the value of the property "PropName" to false. then the property "PropName" will obviously no longer be true, and thus "Property" (sensor) will no longer be true and will not send the positive pulses to "Motion" (actuator) and as a result, the motion will stop.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to increase the `Reset Distance` of the near sensor. If you set it to the maximum of 10000 then the object needs to be 10000 blender units away from the triggering object before it stops moving.